# Multiple vectors on one page in separate plots

Tags: r, plot

I have 20 vectors each of 1000 values and the values range from 0 to 1 in each vector. The range of x-axis is same (x=1,2,3,...,1000) for all vectors and range of y-axis varies from vector to vector.
I want to plot these vectors as shown in the attached image.

[image]

Comment: So you have one vector x and 20 vectors y?

Comment: (sorry, my english is not good) yes, I have 20 vectors each of 1000 values, therefore x is constant and x = 1,2,3,...,1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better solution but here is one. Of course you have to adapt to 20 vectors instead of 6.

```
x <- 1:10
y1 <- rnorm(10)
y2 <- rnorm(10)
y3 <- rnorm(10)
y4 <- rnorm(10)
y5 <- rnorm(10)
y6 <- rnorm(10)

f1 <- gl(2,3)
f2 <- rep(1:3,2)
dat <- data.frame(f1=rep(f1,each=10), 
                  f2=rep(f2,each=10), 
                  id = rep(interaction(f1,f2),each=10))
dat$x <- rep(x,6)
dat$y <- c(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, color=id)) + geom_point(size=2) + 
  facet_wrap(f1~f2, scales = "free_y") +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text.x = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Comment: many thanks @Stephane, I am looking exactly like this. A side question, if I use layout(matrix(c(1:20), nrow=5, ncol=4, byrow = T)), is there a way to adjust the width between plots in the four columns?

Comment: @maqsood.ali When using `layout`, I think the width between plots is due to the margins of the plots. So you have to set `par(mar=c(......))` to control the white space.

Answer (score 0):

See: lattice.r-forge.r-project.org/Vignettes/src/lattice-intro/lattice-intro.pdf

Also search for: R lattice trellis graph plot - you will find an abundance of helpful resources.

Comment: thanks, I have seen this document. these tools do not plot "original data" as I wish, these tools "use" original data and apply some statistical techniques, then plot the results. I want to plot original values

Comment: In my experience, they can plot whatever you want. E.g., have a look at: www.stat.ubc.ca/~jenny/STAT545A/block09_xyplotLattice.html

Comment: Another great option for lattice graphs is Veusz (free, cross platform and exceptionally flexible), especially if you want publication quality graphs.

Comment: thank you @IanRiley, at the moment I have already plotted data using above solution, but I will definitely check Veusz some time later